# Combination of Pivot and Transpose in Python

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I am doing some text analysis, and have a data which kind of looks like this

```
**TABLE 1**
C1   C2          C3

A1  TEXT1   ANOTHER_TEXT1
A2  TEXT1   ANOTHER_TEXT1
B1  TEXT2   ANOTHER_TEXT1
B2  TEXT2   ANOTHER_TEXT1
B3  TEXT2   ANOTHER_TEXT1
D1  TEXT3   ANOTHER_TEXT2
D2  TEXT3   ANOTHER_TEXT2
```

What i really need is a dataset, aggregated over `C2`, and also the contents of `C1` as different columns. Essentially, what a `df.transpose` is supposed to do.
But the problem is that if i transpose, it does not aggregate `C2` and `C3`.

Essentially, this is the structure i am looking at

```
**TABLE 2**
 C1              C2    CT1  CT2  CT3

ANOTHER_TEXT1   TEXT1   A1   A2   NA
ANOTHER_TEXT1   TEXT2   B1   B2   B3
ANOTHER_TEXT2   TEXT3   D1   D2   NA
```

I am trying `df.pivot_table(index=['C2','C3'], aggfunc='count')`, which gives me the count of the occurances, as is correct (Shown Below).

```
**TABLE 3**
 C1              C2    CT1
ANOTHER_TEXT1   TEXT1   2
                TEXT2   3
ANOTHER_TEXT2   TEXT3   2
```

So, how do i get it in the structure i want (Table 2)? Is it at all possible?

If not, what alternatives do i have? As in, which structure would be closest to the one i want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for new columns, then reshape by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html), last [`add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html):

```
df['g'] = df.groupby(['C2','C3']).cumcount() + 1
df = df.set_index(['C2','C3', 'g'])['C1'].unstack().add_prefix('CT').reset_index()
print (df)
      C2             C3 CT1 CT2   CT3
0  TEXT1  ANOTHER_TEXT1  A1  A5    A2
1  TEXT2  ANOTHER_TEXT1  B1  B2    B3
2  TEXT3  ANOTHER_TEXT2  D1  D2  None
```

Another solution with `groupby`, for new columns use `Series` constructor:

```
df = df.groupby(['C2','C3'])['C1'] \
       .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.values)) \
       .unstack() \
       .rename(columns=lambda x: 'CT{}'.format(x+1)) \
       .reset_index()
print (df)
      C2             C3 CT1 CT2   CT3
0  TEXT1  ANOTHER_TEXT1  A1  A5    A2
1  TEXT2  ANOTHER_TEXT1  B1  B2    B3
2  TEXT3  ANOTHER_TEXT2  D1  D2  None
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df.set_index(
    ['C2', 'C3', df.groupby('C2').cumcount() + 1]
).C1.unstack().rename(columns='CT{}'.format)

                    CT1 CT2   CT3
C2    C3                         
TEXT1 ANOTHER_TEXT1  A1  A2  None
TEXT2 ANOTHER_TEXT1  B1  B2    B3
TEXT3 ANOTHER_TEXT2  D1  D2  None
```

Add `reset_index` to get exactly what you wanted

```
df.set_index(
    ['C2', 'C3', df.groupby('C2').cumcount() + 1]
).C1.unstack().rename(columns='CT{}'.format).reset_index()

      C2             C3 CT1 CT2   CT3
0  TEXT1  ANOTHER_TEXT1  A1  A2  None
1  TEXT2  ANOTHER_TEXT1  B1  B2    B3
2  TEXT3  ANOTHER_TEXT2  D1  D2  None
```